# Are there any libraries for embedding Lua in Python using ctypes?

Tags: python, lua, ctypes, embedding

Are there any libraries for doing this yet? If so, are they production quality?

Answer (score 2):

Dunno. But why bother when [Lunatic](http://labix.org/lunatic-python) exists.